# How to change the color of clicked link using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

I have written jquery as following

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var jq = $.noConflict();
     jq(document).ready(function(){
     jq("a.tag-link").click(function(){
     jq(".selected").removeClass("selected");
     jq(this).addClass("selected");
    });
   });
  </script>
```

The html is something like

```
 <a href="home.html"class="tag-link selected" >home</a>
 <a href="about-us.html"class="tag-link" >about us</a>
 <a href="why-us.html"class="tag-link" >why-us</a>
```

In css    `a.selected{color:red;}`
Now my problem is that when I click on let us say about us link, its color get changed to red only when it is clicked. But after it gets redirected to about us page.Its color changes to default one. It does not turn to red. I want that the clicked link should be red color and others should be in default color.Please please help me...

Comment: HTML (and javascript) is somewhat stateless, it does'nt remember stuff from page to page, you'll have use hardcoded values for each page or some sort of storage, like localstorage or cookies. The answer below will work the first time the links are clicked, and once they are visited they will stay red, like forever! If that's what you're after, use CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the entire jQuery code, just use CSS:

```css
a:visited {
    color:#FF0000; /* Or color:red; if you prefer not using the hex codes) */
}
```

The available selectors for the links are:

`a:link {}`
Defines the style for normal unvisited links.

`a:visited {}`
Defines the style for visited links.

`a:active {}`
Defines the style for active links.
A link becomes active once you click on it.

`a:hover {}`
Defines the style for hovered links.
A link is hovered when the mouse moves over it.

([Source](http://www.echoecho.com/csslinks.htm))

Or, if you want this selection to persist when clicking a link, but not apply to all clicked links, use `localStorage`:

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.getItem("clickedLinkId")){ // If "clickedLinkClass" has been set.
        jq('#'+localStorage.getItem("clickedLinkId")).addClass("selected"); // add the class "Selected", to the previously clicked link.
    }
    jq("a.tag-link").click(function(){ // On click
        jq(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        jq(this).addClass("selected");
        localStorage.setItem("clickedLinkId", jq(this).attr("id")); // Save the class of the current element in the localStorage.
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="home.html"class="tag-link selected" id="home" >home</a>
<a href="about-us.html"class="tag-link" id="about" >about us</a>
<a href="why-us.html"class="tag-link" id="why" >why-us</a>
```

This should set the class of a previously clicked link, and store the clicked link in the `localStorage`.

[Working Sample](http://jsbin.com/unatod/2/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the above code will change the color of all the visited link and I want only one of the links i.e selected one should be red color and rest of the others should be of default color.

Comment: In that case you will have to work with something like [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage), [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), or passing parameters.

Comment: Can you please guide me how will i use cookies,localStorage... etc

Comment: I added the above local storage code in my file. It does not wok. please explain it more a bit.

Comment: Oh, found it. Fixing my code, just a moment.
I changed the JavaScript, and added ID's to your links. it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by having a parameter reading function in next page,

***In about-us.html page***

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getURLParameter(id) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(id + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}
$(document).ready(function () { 
    clickedUrl = getURLParameter('id');                 
    if(clickedUrl=='aboutus'){
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $('#aboutus').addClass("selected");
    }
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
a.selected{color:red;}
</style>


<a id="home" href="home.html?id=home" class="tag-link selected" >home</a>
 <a id="aboutus" href="about-us.html?id=aboutus" class="tag-link" >about us</a>
 <a id="yus" href="why-us.html?id=yus" class="tag-link" >why-us</a>
```

Comment: Didnt think of that @Cerbrus, suppose it was not on the question, but its a good thing you're asking, because parameters will be there in the bookmark.

Comment: My point exactly. Depending on what the user wants, this can be a strong or weak point of this answer... +1 any way.

Comment: you are correct @Cerbrus, and if i a find workaround to overcome that part ill post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a link to /home.html to be red when you are actually on /home.html but not otherwise, just parse the current url

```
var selectedLink = location.href.replace(/http:\/\/[^\/]+\//i,'/');
$('a[href="' + selectedLink + '"]').addClass('selected');
```

you just need to either make your link paths absolute, or change the replacement to chop off everything before the final slash like:

```
var selectedLink = location.href.replace(/http:\/\/.*\/([^\/]+)/i,"$1");
```